# Rails SQL query for many-to-many column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, psql

I've got three models - `user` `journey_progress` and `journey` with below associations:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :journey_progresses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :journeys, through: :journey_progresses
end

class JourneyProgress < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :journey
end

class Journey < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, through: :journey_progresses
  has_many :journey_progresses, dependent: :destroy

  validates :percent_progress, inclusion: 0.0..1.0
end
```

In my endpoint I want to return all user `journeys` with `percent_progress` (it's a column of `journey_progress` module - journey_progress.percent_progress) for each `journey`. How to display that in one query?

What I've done is:

In `current_user` I can do:

`progress = current_user.journey_progresses` which gives me:

```
[46] pry(main)> progress = current_user.journey_progresses
  JourneyProgress Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "journey_progresses".* FROM "journey_progresses" WHERE "journey_progresses"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
=> [#<JourneyProgress:0x00007ffaf9b86cc0 id: 1, user_id: 1, journey_id: 2, percent_progress: 1.0, created_at: Mon, 20 Jul 2020 23:00:27 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Mon, 20 Jul 2020 23:08:58 UTC +00:00, started_at: nil, finished_at: Mon, 20 Jul 2020 23:08:58 UTC +00:00>]
```

Now I can catch journeys:

```
Journey.where(id: progress.each { |progress| progress.journey_id })
```

But I don't know how to display `percent_progress` for each user journey.

Comment: But what for? I want to display `current_user.journeys` with `percent_progress` for each journey

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: `current_user.journeys.includes(:journey_progresses).joins(:journey_progresses).each { |journey_progress| puts journey_progress.percent_progress }`

Comment: it gives `NoMethodError: undefined method 'percent_progress' for #<Journey:0x00007ffaf16ad300>`

Comment: Ups, the object is supposed to be a collection of journeys, so it must be something like `current_user.journeys.includes(:journey_progresses).joins(:journey_progresses).each { |journey| puts journey.journey_progresses.each { |journey_progress| puts journey_progress.percent_progress } }`.

Comment: You have to access each journey_progress from each user journey and then you're able to print the percent progress from each journey_progress. Correct me if I'm wrong, I haven't replicated your scenario yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need data from JourneyProgress (`percent_progress`) and Journey. You want to make 2 queries total (not one for each Journey).

You original solution was somewhat close. What you did in the end, finding all Journeys by their ids after finding all the journey progresses is a good idea, but there's no point doing it yourself. Rails already has it built-in. It's called `includes`.

```
current_user.journey_progresses.includes(:journey)
```

Now rails will do 2 queries (sometimes even 1) and associate the journeys with each progress. Now if you just call `journey` on each progress, no additional queries will be made.

Since you didn't specify how you wanted your data in the end, I'll just demonstrate how you would get an array of arrays with `percent_progress` and `Journey` in it.

```
current_user.journey_progresses.includes(:journey).map do |journey_progress|
  [journey_progress.percent_progress, journey_progress.journey]
end
```